# How to improve logistic regression in R

Tags: r, logistic

I'm trying to improve the performance of a logistic regression in R to a dataset similar to this one but with more columns and rows :

```
df = data.frame(c('1','1','0','1','0'), c('5','4','1','4','2'), c('11,3','4.1','6.0','7.4','4.9'), c('0','1','1','0','0')) 
names(df) <- c("dead", "A", "B", "C")
```

(I want to predict if the person is dead or not)

For the moment i used the significance of the variables provided by the glm model and test different combinations with them :

```
model <- glm(dead~., family=binomial(link='logit'), data=df)

# Create ordered dataframe with the name variable and its p-value
pval <- as.data.frame(coef(summary(model))[,4] )
pval <- setDT(pval, keep.rownames = TRUE)[]
names(pval) <- c('variable', 'p')
pval <-pval[!(pval$variable=="(Intercept)"),]
pval <-as.data.frame(pval[order(pval[,2],decreasing=F), ])

# Compare performance of different combinaisons
for (i in 1:nrow(pval) ) {
   var <- c("dead")
   for(j in 0:i){
      var <- append(var, pval['variable'][j,])
      tempSubset <- train[,var ]
      glm.fit <- glm(dead~., family=binomial(link='logit'), data=tempSubset)
      p = predict(glm.fit, test, type="response")
      pr = prediction(p, test$sortie)
      auc = performance(pr, measure = "auc")

      cat('Variables selected: ', var, '\n AUC : ', auc@y.values[[1]], '\n \n ')
   }

}
```

How could i improve the performande of this logistic regression ?
Maybe by creating combinations of one variable like that ?

```
glm.fit <- glm(dead~ A+A², family=binomial(link='logit'), data=tempSubset)
```

or combinationts of different variables:

```
glm.fit <- glm(dead~ A:B, family=binomial(link='logit'), data=tempSubset)
```

The number of possibilities is huge, therefore how can I find the most suitable combinations according to the type of variable or its distribution ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Do you have to make the prediction with logistic regression? There are other algorithms that you could try to see if you can get a better result: Decision Trees, Random Forest, SVM and so on. More over, you could try a more Machine Learning approach and divide your data is *training* and *test* datasets.

Comment: In general, you could try transforming your variables (squaring, as you show, or log, or other transforms), using interaction terms, smoothing (say, with a GAM), partial pooling (GLMM) if your data has any hierarchy, using regularization to do shrinkage and variable selection ...  Or you could try different models. While the question isn't on-topic here, it may be too broad there. Perhaps try a textbook on machine learning or predictive modeling.

Comment: There are ways, but do you really want to? It sounds like you'll overfit and have a model that performs poorly when fit to new data.

Comment: Yes, you could investigate interactions or squaring some independent variables (although if their values are 0 and 1 that won't get you far).  If you have many potential independent variables, you might look into LASSO or ridge regression.

Comment: There are many ways, but be careful. Remember, "if you torture the data enough, they will confess to anything" (from Ronald Coase).